# Excel - Need a formula/ or any other help in extracting Data

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I need to find a faster way to extract data form a list. I have a file i wanted to attach so you may have an idea of what I am actually referring to, but couldn't.

On the first tab I have a list with all the individuals and in each column a data referring to them. On this list individuals may appear more than once as they the data is for the whole year for every paydate ( 2x a month). From this list ( 8000 rows), I need only the data for certain individuals ( sheet 2 of the file).

I need a solution to extract all the rows from the list for these specific individuals. In the past I have had to manually use the filter list and filter them. I have tried vlookup but that brings up only the first entry it finds.

Comment: May be Pivot Table might help.

Answer (score 0):

A VLOOKUP with a creative approach should do the trick. If you add a VLOOKUP formula on the first tab to lookup the names (or whatever the unique identifier is) from the second tab you will get a mix of VLOOKUP'd values and `#N/A`. If you then filter to exclude the `#N/A`s you will be left with the records of the certain individuals and can modify them there or copy & paste them to a different worksheet/workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Try to approach it the other wat around: instead of showing the rows from tab 1 on tab 2, try to identify on tab 1 which persons should be shown.

Suppose the names are in column A of tab 1 and tab 2, add a column to to table of tab 1 with a vlookup to tab 2: `=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1, tab2!$A$1:$A$999, 0, FALSE)))`. This gives `TRUE` if the name is in tab 2 (not #NA) and `FALSE` if it isn’t.

Next, you can set a filter on the table in tab 1. Or a bit more fancy, create a pivot table from tab 1 with a page filter that selects only those persons that appear on tab 2.